# Haskell, sum up two elements of a list with pattern matching?

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

i am learning the pattern syntax in Haskell and now i have a problem with my small function.

I want to add two elements of a list like in the example:

```
input 1: [1,2,3,4,5],  output2: [3,5,7,9]

input 2: [1,2,3,4,5,6],  ouput 2: [3,5,7,11]
```

My Code(i tried to make a pattern for two elements but it says that the patterns are overlapping):

```
g4 [] = []
g4 [x] = [] 
-- g4 (x:y:xs) = x+y: g4 xs
g4 (x:y:z:xs) = x+y:y+z: g4 (xs)
```

It should look like this, but i dont know how to create the pattern for 2 elements:

```
g1 [1,2,3,4,5]
 = 1+2 : 2+3 : g1 [3,4,5]
          = 3+4 : 4+5 : g1 [5]
               = []


g1 [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 = 1+2 : 2+3 : g1 [3,4,5,6]
          = 3+4 : 4+5 : g1 [5,6]  
                = 5+6
```

Test:

```
*Main> g4 [1,2,3]
[3,5] -- worked
*Main> g4 [1,2,3,4]
[3,5,4] -- did not work
*Main> g4 [1,2,3,4,5]
*** Exception: Test.hs:(127,1)-(130,32): Non-exhaustive patterns in function g4 -- didnt work

[3,5*Main> g4 [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[3,5,9,11] -- worked
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `g4` on the combination of `(y:xs)` for your recursive component:

```
g4 [] = []
g4 [x] = []
g4 (x:y:xs) = x+y : g4 (y:xs)
```

Comment: It worked, but why do you use g4(y:xs) and not g4(xs)?

Comment: Taking your example `[1,2,3,4]`, the flow looks like this: `g4 (1:2:[3,4]) = 1+2 : g4 (2:[3,4])`, `g4 (2:3:[4]) = 2+3 : g4 (3:[4])`, `g4 (3:4:[]) = 3+4 : g4 (4:[])`, `g4 [4] = []`. Combining those all together you get `[1+2, 2+3, 3+4]`.

Comment: Ah now i understand! Thats for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can just zip the list with a "shifted" version of itself.

```
g4 xs = zipWith (+) xs (tail xs)
```